# Best way to store temperature data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a question regarding temperature data:
With mysql i stored the temperature data like this:

```
city_id;city_name;month;min_temperature,max_temperature
123,New York,1,7,9
```

For now i want to move to mongodb and would like to store the data document orientated
The structure now would look like this:

```
{
  "_id" : 20480,
  "name": "New York"
  "climate" : {
    "air" : {
      "1" : {
        "min" : "1",
        "max" : "8"
      },
      "2" : {
        "min" : "2",
        "max" : "8"
      },
      "3" : {
        "min" : "3",
        "max" : "10"
      },
      "..."
    }
  }
}
```

Does anybody have some experience with that structure or any tips to optimize this ?
Does this structure make sense or would it be better to do it like this:

```
{
      "_id" : 20480,
      "name": "New York"
      "climate" : {
        "air" : {
          "january" : {
            "min" : "1",
            "max" : "8"
          },
          "february" : {
            "min" : "2",
            "max" : "8"
          },
          "march" : {
            "min" : "3",
            "max" : "10"
          },
          "..."
        }
      }
    }
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- This strucutre seems good

:

```
 {
          "_id" : 20480,
          "name": "New York"
          "climate" : {
            "air" : {
              "january" : {
                "min" : "1",
                "max" : "8"
              },
              "february" : {
                "min" : "2",
                "max" : "8"
              },
              "march" : {
                "min" : "3",
                "max" : "10"
              },
              "..."
            }
          }
        }
```

This makes it clear in the document for what month the data is, using "1","2" etc would have saved you some disk space as mongoDb keys use space repetitively for each record.
But as your data would not be millions of documents, you are fine with using "january","february" . You may want to use "jan","feb","mar" though to keep the key names shorter as well as descriptive.

- Now, you would want to keep in consideration what kind of queries you would be making on your data. eg.

  a) Which city had max air temperature in March ?
  b) Which all cities had max temperature between 8 to 12 ?

  c) Which city had maximum average min temperature throughout the year ? etc

You will get some results with direct queries and proper indexing,but may have to use map reduce for advanced data needs.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Either one will be good.
or you can have this:

```
"air" : [{min:1,max:5},{min:2,max:6}, {min:5,max:15} ... ]
```

use array instead.  Of course, 0 = Jan.

It depends on if you do this more,  climate.air.january  or you will do a loop and do this more: climate.air[0]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But are there some advantages to use the array structure you mentioned ?